# StyleableTextField width not honored

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

How can I enable width correctly on the StyleableTextField.
Below is the sample code.

Expectation: The background red color should cover the entire width.

Actual: The red color just covers the text.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    viewActivate="onViewActivate(event)">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;
    import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

    private function onViewActivate( event:ViewNavigatorEvent ):void
    {
        var txtMobile:StyleableTextField = new StyleableTextField();

        txtMobile.text              = "Hello World";
        txtMobile.background        = true;
        txtMobile.backgroundColor   = 0xFF0000;

        txtMobile.width             =  FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width;

        this.addElement( txtMobile );
    }
]]>
</fx:Script>
```

I have also tried disabling the autoSize property

```
txtMobile.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try using a Label. I guess the background color will spread across the breadth of a spark label and since there are no borders/boundaries to it, you won't have this problem